# Insert space after specific amount of numbers within a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I got an array with a lot of strings that are badly formatted.
I need to add a space to the string after the first three numbers within the String with **JavaScript**. The main problem is that I don't have a specific index to insert the space because the number of characters before the first three numbers vary or dont exist at all.

**Example Input:**

```json
[
   "A12345678",
   "ABC12345678",
   "1234 56 7 8",
   "12 345 67 8",
   "AB12345678BVC",
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```json
[
   "A123 45678",
   "ABC123 45678",
   "123 45678",
   "123 45678",
   "AB123 45678BVC",
]
```

I thought it may be solvable with `replaceAll` spaces to get an unbroken string and then do a `for loop` over each character per string and then solve this by type checking the characters to add a space at the desired position, but I get a huge amount of these arrays from the backend and it may end up in a terrible performance this way.

The other idea I got is to solve this by using Regex like in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript-insert-space-after-every-two-letters-in-string) example from a tutorial, but unfortunately I suck at writing Regex. I'd be really grateful if somebody can help me with this.

Comment: please share what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String.replace()` along with `Array.map()` to add the required space. First of all we remove all spaces from each string, then add the space at the required position.

```js
const input = [
   "A12345678",
   "ABC12345678",
   "1234 56 7 8",
   "12 345 67 8",
   "AB12345678BVC",
]

const result = input.map(v => v.replace(/\s/g,'').replace(/(\d{3})/, '$1 '));
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
const texts = [
  "A12345678",
  "ABC12345678",
  "1234 56 7 8",
  "12 345 67 8",
  "AB12345678BVC"
]
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text, '->', text.replace(/\s+/g,'').replace(/\d{3}(?!$)/, '$& '));
}
```

I.e.

- Remove whitespaces first, then
- Add space after first 3 digits if these digits are not at the end of the string.